# Display Alert Messages Conditionally On Concurrent program Parameters using special value sets in oracle apps

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql, report

Using Oracle EBS . Basically I have two parameters - Start date and End Date in my concurrent program. Initially both should be enabled. the program should allow the user to submit if both are blank. but if we leave start date blank and populate end date , it should display alert or error that start date is mandatory in this case.How can this be implemented?

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question?

Comment: Yes so basically I have added value type none to start date and in the end date value set (special) I have added to validate :                                  FND PLSQL "DECLARE
ld_date DATE := TO_DATE(:!VALUE,'DD-MON-YYYY');
ld_month_start DATE := TO_DATE(':$FLEX$.XXCUST_CURRENT_MONTH','DD-MON-YYYY');
BEGIN 
   IF ld_date IS NOT NULL AND ld_month_start IS NULL
   THEN
       fnd_message.set_name('AMCCUST','DATE_INPUT_ERROR');
       fnd_message.set_token('VAL','Input date is not with in current month');
      fnd_message.raise_error;     
   END IF;
END;"

Comment: Please edit your question first. Please don't show your code in the comment.